# How to submit a form as soon as all inputs are filled in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a form like this(simplified):

```
handleSubmit(e){
   e.preventDefault();
}
render(){
   return (
       <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <input type="text" maxLength="1"/>
          <input type="text" maxLength="1"/>
          <input type="text" maxLength="1"/>
          <input type="text" maxLength="1"/>
       </form>
   )
}
```

As you can see, there is no button to submit a form since I want to automatically submit a form when a user filled all inputs.
Also, just to be clear, I'm **not** trying to find out how to submit a form with enter key.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you consider as "filled all inputs"? E.g. do you consider all fields to be filled when all of them have a value *and* none of them has focus? If not, how do you want to determine that the user finished filling out the last input?

Comment: @FelixKling I consider all fields to be filled when all of them have a value. I am not really sure what you mean by none of them has focus. I want a form to be submitted once each input has a value.

Comment: Basically, how do you know that the user finished typing? The answer you accepted will submit the form as soon as the user typed a single character in the last input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an input create value attribute state and assign an onchange handler to the input. On every change set the state of the input state variable. If the value of all four of the state variables is set then call the `handleSubmit` function. Below is the sampple snippet.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    
  }
}
  handleSubmit(){
   console.log('Perform submit acction now');
}
  handleChange(e) {
   this.setState({[e.target.id]: e.target.value}, function() {
   var obj = this.state
   var count = 0;
   if(Object.keys(this.state).length == 4) {
   Object.keys(this.state).forEach(function(key){
     if(obj[key] !== '') {
       count++;
     }
   });
     if(count == 4) {
       this.handleSubmit();
     }
     }
});
  }
render(){
   return (
       <form ref="form1" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <input type="text" id="inp1" maxLength="1" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.inp1} />
          <input type="text" id="inp2" maxLength="1" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.inp2}/>
          <input type="text" id="inp3" maxLength="1" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.inp3}/>
          <input type="text" id="inp4" maxLength="1" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.inp4}/>
       </form>
   )
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Good one ;) Should be the answer for him

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Add a ref to each input. Inside the component have a state where you have ready:false and make it true when the last input as been filled and all other is filled to. Make an action who is ON only when the state ready:true.

With the ref you can see if each input has value. Something you can do too it's disabled the other input if the first one has no value. So you can track the filled stuff and see when they came to the last one you know you got your stuff.

With the small amount of detail you give, I just try to help you with an idea hope that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* if inputs are automatically filled*/ 
f1=React.createRef()  
componentDidUpdate() {
     this.f1.current.submit();
}
render() {
return (<React.Fragment>
<Form action="localhost/bla-bla" method="POST" ref={this.f1}>
    <Form.Control type="text" value="hello"/>
</Form>
</React.Fragment>
)}
```